# What could be causing a font to appear "chunky" when rendered?

Tags: html, css, fonts, frontend

I'm working on a web project and one of the fonts in particular (Rosewood Std Fill) is appearing chunky when rendered in the browser. See chunky version below rendered in Chrome and regular version rendered in Illustrator. I apologize they are different sizes.

[image]

[image]

In any case the font weight and style are both set to "normal". I'm not really sure what steps to take to try to resolve this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome has very poor default AA. Try adding the following CSS to your text.

```
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
```

or

```
 -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased
```

They have different results depending on whether your background is light or dark. Try them both to see which looks better in your situation.